# What is the best way to pass parameters to a callback function? (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c

I'm learning SDL right now and I'm trying to use timer callback function.

The function SDL_AddTimer() offer me only one argument to pass through but I want to pass different types of variables into it.
(https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_AddTimer)

I think of one solution is that I can declare a structure containing all of my variables but I'm not sure if it is the best way to do so.

Thank you for your help ~~

Comment: That is _the_ way. What other ways could there possibly be? ;-)

Comment: Just try and see what happens. ;-)

Comment: @underscore_d Some people have the habit of using the dirty crap hack of casting an integer to a void* then cast back to an integer from inside the callback. Very brittle and bad code, but seems somewhat common.

Comment: @Lundin that's only relying on `intptr_t` being an alias for `int`, which (used to be) incredibly common

Comment: Using such a struct is the way to go. You just need to keep in mind that the lifetime of the struct where your argument points to must be long enough.

Comment: @Caleth Except pointers are 64 bits on a whole lot of systems now. And you can also in theory get alignment problems, trap representations etc. And converting the value 0 to a pointer isn't a brilliant idea either. We should simply refrain from using brittle, stupid hacks. It's not rocket science to allocate a `static int` and pass a pointer to that one...

Comment: ..but not thread-safe or particularly flexible. If you mallocate the data, instead of static, you can safely have multiple callbacks outstanding and cope with callbacks fired from different threads.

Comment: @underscore_d Thank you~ I just thought if there might be a fancy technique!

Comment: @Lundin I'm not fully understand what the bad habit is which you refer to. 
Does it mean that some people will write code like below?
 int a = 2; 
void* b = &a;
then pass b into callback function and cast  b back to integer in that function

Comment: @Gerhardh I will mind that! Thank you~

Comment: @MartinJames sorry I cannot understand what you said. Which one is not thread-safe or particularly flexible?

Comment: .....static data:(  If you mallocate the callback data, you don't have to concern yourself with its lifetime in the setup code or worry that another thread could try to setup another callback, so changing static data before/while a previous callback is using it.  Yes, the callback itself has to deal with the allocation, eg. by freeing it after use, or maybe queueing it on to yet another thread for later use, (eg. a logger thread).  See how easy and flexible it is once you get out of the misery of global/static data and the dire join:)

Comment: @Benasking7124 No, the scenario I speak of is `void* p = (void*)some_integer` and then pass the pointer to the callback, then inside the callback cast back `int x = (int)p;`.

Comment: @MartinJames You should preferably not be passing the same data to multiple threads, so there is no thread safety issue with `static` unless you create one. I'm talking about the thread parameters, nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think of one solution is that I can declare a structure containing all of my variables but I'm not sure if it is the best way to do so.

Yes this is the correct and best way to pass parameters whenever you are presented with a callback that accepts `void*`. Then cast back to the struct type from inside the callback.

Same thing goes when using pthreads/Windows threads or other such common APIs.

Comment: I see!! Thank you~~